# use the cli of winrar to backup outlook pst

Tags: command-line-interface, outlook, rar

hello is it possible to use the winrar cli to backup a pst file. i have outlook openend 24/7 so the file is locked.

i use the following command:

```
C:\Backup>"c:\Program Files\WinRAR\rar.exe" a meel.rar c:\Users\CapSoft\AppData\Local\Microsoft\Outlook\*.*
```

but i only get a message that it is currently in use, how can i resolve this?
is it even possible to back it up when outlook is openend?

when i close outlook it works.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'm none too thrilled with the idea that a PT file should be backed up while outlook is opened.  It is however possible so long as you are on XP or above.  See this [link](http://blogs.msdn.com/adioltean/archive/2005/01/05/346793.aspx) for a script that will make a copy of the file using vshadow to create a shadow copy on the fly.  After you have a copy you will be able to use your rar command to compact the file.

Comment: i have windows 7 pro. will take a look at your link thanks!

Comment: pff a lot of work, i will just close outlook. though thanks for the link

Comment: Outlook has a mechanism for backing up or archiving data (at least it did the last time I messed with it).  Just configure it to do a nightly archive to a known PST file and location, RAR up the resulting files, then delete them.